# How to pass object to soap webservice in BlackBerry using C++

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, blackberry

I am New to BlackBerry development. I am using Momentics for Blackberry development. Now I want to pass an object to my Login webservice. Here is my webservice.

```
<Login xmlns="http://shidhints.com/">
  <MyLoginCredentials>
    <Email>string</Email>
    <Password>string</Password>
  </MyLoginCredentials>
</Login>
```

How I can create an object of **MyLoginCredentials** in C++, Please Help me.

Comment: Only took me a quick search and a couple of clicks to get to the Soap sample, that you will find on this page.  http://developer.blackberry.com/native/sampleapps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Resolved it Using the code,

```
QtSoapStruct *myStruct=new QtSoapStruct(QtSoapQName("MyLoginCredentials"));
myStruct->insert( new QtSoapSimpleType(QtSoapQName("Email"), email));
myStruct->insert( new QtSoapSimpleType(QtSoapQName("Password"),password));

request.addMethodArgument(myStruct);
```